# Android Studio Component Tree has moved to a different bar

Tags: xml, android-studio, palette

Just messed around with some features of Android Studio and got my Component Tree stuck in a different bar than the palette one, as you can see in the pictures:

when both of the bars are closed:
[image: when both of the bars are closed]

when both of the bars are open:
[image: when both of the bars are open]

No matter what I tried I can't get it back to the 2nd inner bar of the palette and it is really impposibble to edit the XML file without it.
I tried to do shift + F12 and it only hides and unhides the component tree but does not make it come back to the inner bar as it was the default way.

Comment: Window > WorkSpace > Reset Default Layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore the layout from

> Window > Restore Default Layout.

Or using the keyboard shortcut 
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: Does not work mate. Please look that I have already stated that I tried doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The component tree is not attached to any side.

Expand the component tree -> click settings icon of the component tree panel -> select attached side to left.

or

Right-click on the component tree panel -> select attached side to left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click `Component Tree` in your fig 1, and remove the check of `Floating Mode`, after that click `Left` in `Attached Side`.